# restrict user to copy content from textarea in flex3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I am trying to built something like this:

http://tourdeflex.adobe.com/flex4.0/TextLayoutFrameworkBasic/sample2.html

User can not copy content from textarea in flex3. How can i implement this functionality?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this property to your textarea tag:

```
selectable="false"
```